# How do I delete wires in Cadence?

Tags: cadence

I'm losing my mind. I click delete, and try to select the wire and just can't do it. Nothing on the Internet explains it.

Comment: Dumbest and maybe most annoying possible thing I can say right now but.....  Did you reboot your computer???

Comment: Next step after rebooting: read the manual! If that doesn't work for you, follow a course to learn how to use the software or call Cadence.

Comment: Someone suggests to close the question for being off-topic but I'm voting to keep it open. Asking questions on using CAD programs for electronic design, even basic questions, are on-topic. If how to [select components](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/262781/how-can-i-drag-select-components-in-a-room-in-altium/438579) or [scroll the screen](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/415381/scrolling-screen-in-altium-16) in Altium Designer are on-topic, deleting a wire in Cadence should be on-topic too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select Edit->Delete (or the red X icon)

Open the Find window (Display->Windows->Find)

The Find window shows all the things that can now be deleted.
Select the "Clines" box in order to be able to delete entire traces, or "Cline seg" to delete just a segment.

**WARNING!!!** Do NOT select "Nets" to delete traces - this will delete all nets on your board with that net name. For example, if you delete a little ground trace it will rip up all other grounds on your board. And you may not notice until much later, after you've made a ton more changes. Yes, I've done it. More than once.

So in general when Cadence appears to misbehave, take a look at the Find window. This is the scope for whatever operation you are doing - move, copy, delete etc.

And be careful when multiple boxes are selected: if say, Clines and Nets are both selected, Allegro will make a decision on which to use and it might not be what you wanted - be explicit about which boxes are selected to avoid mishap.